# Create some Table in a single Sheet on Excel with Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

[xlsxwriter code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZDhQ.png)[xlsxwriter code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOhc2.png)I would like to create three different tables (with different sizes and different merged/colored header) in a single sheet in Excel using Python.in the tables data is read in with a loop line by line. I first came up with the idea of using pandas but it seemed quite complicated. I personally use OpenpyXl to work in Excel Workbook but I'm still a beginner. Do you have some ideas for me or what can you recommend me to do or use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/). It has much less overhead than pandas if you *only* want to dump tables with formats

Comment: I have used Xlsxwriter and yes it works to some extent but I want to make a table like this 3 times and in different sizes. 
The data is also big in each case and I don't have it with the header_format in this case. What would you do to have 3 tables in the same sheet and the first list is always the column names. Or can I use Openpyxl wih pandas. I thought I could build my sheet (so with header formatting and undefined size) and then just read in line by line the data in any form.